How to deal with disastrous technical leadership
I am on an important team in a tech company. Our technical leader is consistently making bad decisions. By 'bad' I mean going against industry standards and best practices, consistently increasing complexity, while lowering maintainability, and raising future development costs.
Aside from technical issues, our processes and infrastructure are on the same disastrous level. Communicating issues within the team is strongly discouraged. Infrastructural solutions are outdated by a decade.
A single technical leadership person is the source of all of above.
I have made multiple attempts at raising issues and suggesting improvements, and have watched teammates do so, to no avail.
I would prefer to keep this job for various reasons, but this situation is killing me.
Is there anything I could do beside quitting? I wish desperately there were some options I'm not seeing.


Do your peers agree with your views? 2) How many levels above you is the technical leader?


How high up in the chain of command are you and this technical leader? Would you be able to express the problems in terms that the non-technical leadership can understand (primarily money; profits & losses)? and what kind of backlash might occur when you make the non-technical leadership aware, based on how well you know them, they know you and they know this technical leader?

@PhilipKendall 1) in short: yes. this has been going on for a long time now, I have checked myself to make sure the problem is not in me; 2) there's a manager between us

@BartvanIngenSchenau I am a lead developer. There was an incident where a colleague got fired - can't share details as I'll get deanonymized, but that's the kind of backlash I expect here. I don't personally know high leadership, should I try to somehow get noticed by them? I'm not sure how to do that. It seems to me if I present the upper management with a presentation about our problems it will be my word against the tech lead. My expectation is they bullshit their way out of it and I get fired.

Is this a Hanlon's Razor? Are they too stupid to know how wrong their are and not willing to listen to ideas?

@DogBoy37 I think it's the combination of self confidence, outdated knowledge, and the desire to implement a unique vision. Not exactly stupidity. The vision is unique, mind, it's just uniquely bad. None of the devs I spoke to about it believed we're doing what we're doing, it's that ridiculous.

Is internal transfer to a different manager an option for you?

@burningdev  Nothing wrong with unique vision - if the logic holds up to a smell test. It sounds like in this case that it doesn't. The best way to rattle the cage is to point out the security holes in decade old thinking. If no one in the management chain cares after some clear examples of security holes, then you have your answer about the company as a long term career.

What part of the situation "is killing you"?

Do you have enough experience to be certain that you are the one who is right here?  There may be things you do not know yet.

You're using the word "saboteur" which implies intent. As mentioned in a comment, this is Hanlon's Razor in which you're assuming malice rather than incompetence or stupidity.
Your best option at this point is to continue doing your very best work. Continue to work towards best practices. Continue to suggest modifications to processes and behaviors that lead to positive outcomes.
I think the thing in your way is that you're expecting them to be you. They don't have your knowledge, skills, and experience. So the best you can do is to continue advocating. Stop demanding radical change. Begin applying incremental change. With every small improvement you can inject into the system, over time the change will be the large shift you want.
From reading your question though, it sounds to me like you've already quit.  You just haven't left the company. Quit quitting.
Believe. Do. Repeat.

Thank you for your reply, it is quite interesting.
I wanted to clarify a couple of things though.

I used 'saboteur' as a way to show the extent of the damage done. I very much doubt there is an evil intent here, although if it appeared to be so, it would make total sense. So please forgive me being a bit dramatic with that word.
Second thing, no amount of small changes will undo the incredible core decision made by the technical lead. It's a real pain both to maintain our systems and to evolve them. If we got a new leadership today, it would take us more than a year to gradually fix all the parts of our system and our processes, provided we only do that and don't add new functionality.

@burningdev - I refute your second point vociferously. Nothing will change if nothing changes. Be the change. I refer you to the parable of the starfish. https://eventsforchange.wordpress.com/2011/06/05/the-starfish-story-one-step-towards-changing-the-world/

To the folks who suggest an edit of changing "Quit quitting" to "Quiet quitting" - I said what I said, and the two phrases are not congruent.

@burningdev You've got a hard sell.  "If we got a new leadership today, it would take us more than a year to gradually fix all the parts of our system and our processes, provided we only do that and don't add new functionality."  If the mess your are using now is still bringing in money, it is still more advantageous to the company than paying devs for a year with no cash coming  in.  Unless, that is, you'll cover the sunk costs of the fix with future revenues.  Money is what drives companies, not necessarily neat code or efficient systems (unfortunately?)

@JoelEtherton I was an approver of an edit to "Quiet Qutting". I understand what you mean now, but it was very far from obvious when I was reviewing the edit (I read both your post and the question when reviewing), and I only understand what you mean now by trying to understand why you might possibly roll the edit back. Something like "Stop Quitting" might be more clear?

To clarify what I mean - you perfectly describe "quiet quitting" in the first two sentences of your final paragraph, and then tell the OP to stop doing that. The edited paragraph mistakenly clarifies that you are saying the OP has quietly quit (which I now understand you didn't intend), which is why I suggest something less ambiguous.

@PlayerOne it is only ambiguous if you read words that aren't there. "Quit quitting" is short, simple and precise. "Quiet quitting" is not a sentence, it's a fragment.

How about "Quit quiet-quitting."?

@Theodore I said what I said.

If you're dealing with bad leadership, bad technical decision maker, then your product will be impacted by critical incident sooner or later. When it comes, be a part of solution, not the problem. Show them how to fix, show them how to do the right thing the right way. Maybe at the end, your leader will be replaced by you or somebody else.

There are two possible scenarios here.

You are correct in your assessment.  In which case, nothing is going to make a change any time soon.  It can take years to rise up in an organisation where they see your worth and take your opinions seriously.  In other organisations, this is never going to happen because an incompetent is in charge.
You are incorrect in your assessment because they company is not doing the things the way you would like them done.  It doesn't necessarily make those actions wrong, just different.

In either case, the best course of action for you is to leave on your own terms.

In case 1, why do you assume OP won't want to be part of a longer-term change?  (As already mentioned, gradual bottom-up change is often possible — and may be better in the long run — than top-down change.)  And in case 2, why is leaving the best course of action, rather than OP learning to accept it and adjust their expectations/practices?

I wish it was #2. But we're making debug impossible, we're shutting down discussions, we're implementing things others call crazy, while not having any speed or performance benefits, and all that for the tasks rather trivial, already done by a bunch of companies

You did not clarify if the project is software or not, but it is not very important because:

either it is software, and you are dealing with spaghetti code;
or it is not software, but it is the equivalent of spaghetti code.


[...] going against industry standards and best practices, consistently increasing complexity, while lowering maintainability, and raising future development costs.
Aside from technical issues, our processes and infrastructure are on the same disastrous level. [...] Infrastructural solutions are outdated by a decade.

And those are all characteristics of unmaintainable spaghetti code.
And now the answer is simple - your situation is not unique, at all. The questions about how to deal with unmaintainable code (and its managers) are abundant everywhere on the internet. Just search for "spaghetti code", "unmaintainable project" and similar, and you will see.
What you can do (just a few ideas, feel free to find other solutions if applicable):

Just go along. If it works, do not fix it.
Make small gradual improvements as you go. The most obvious improvement - improve documentation: requirements, test cases, architecture etc. Everything and anything that you would like to have and you do not have.
Create a "child" project - totally outside of the original. Replace one of the old technologies with a new technology. Prove that it works at least as good as the original, with no bad or unwanted behaviors. Release. Repeat. Do not forget to do this (especially the release to production) with the knowledge and approval of management.
Redo the project from scratch. Or almost from scratch - you do not need to re-create the universe. Show that it works better and safer than the original. Release.

Just be careful about the "prove that it works" and "release" parts. They can create huge problems if done improperly. Do not slip the upgrades to production during overtime on Friday evening.
If you feel abhorred to undertake any of the above challenges, then you feel exactly how your technical leader feels. I was in your shoes several times - that is how I learned to be more understanding with such situations. Maybe your technical leader is as upset as you are about the current state of things, but overall, if the risk of change is much bigger than the benefit - then the risk is not worth taking.

Without knowing what type of decisions we are talking about (cloud vs on-prem / single vendor vs multi vendor / Rust vs Python vs Haskell) it is hard to be specific. But there are often considerations which aren't purely technical (e.g. avoiding vendor lock-in, or a legal need to keep certain data on-site).
If a specific project is failing (not just over-running - overruns are all too common) this will get noticed. No-one likes cancelled projects. And if you can highlight your concerns up-front (subtly) this has a good chance to be remembered when the project is cancelled down the road.
But otherwise, if we are just talking about decisions with which you disagree and you feel make yours and others' jobs harder - you need to try to become involved in the decision making process. Don't jump straight to a solution, and don't invest yourself in a single solution. Instead:

Get alignment on what a "good" solution should offer (good price / performance, scalability, ease of use etc)
Gather input on a whole range of possible solutions - nothing is off the table
Assess all of these solutions against the points raised in 1.

But if you are dealing with a "starchitect" who has an utterly closed decision-making process, you most likely need to move on.

You have basically two choices. Quit at any time you find a better job (but the grass is always greener on the other side) or wait until this technical leader leaves.
At that point you get a new technical leader. If you were right, hopefully that new leader realises that he or she inherited a steaming pile of excrement. At that point, observe them and learn. I'd probably give you a choice of picking ten percent of a years work to improve something that is really bad and will pay back when improved, plus identify a person who is especially good at improving existing rubbish and not so good at creating new things. Then after a year things are a tiny bit less bad.
